# URL path to view with certain filters selected is altered by Drupal when used as a menu link

Tags: routes, uri

I have a view with different filter options. I need to create some links to the view that will automatically select certain filters simply by following the link.

If I copy the url created on the view page when you chose a filter, and then past the url into a new browser it works. The page loads with the same filter selection chosen.

> mysite/resources?tid%5B%5D=22&tid%5B%5D=23&tid%5B%5D=24&tid%5B%5D=25&tid_1%5B%5D=26&keys=

Howeve when I try and use the url as a menu path it doesnt work. It links to the page but without the filter selected. When I edit the path I can see that Drupal has changed it:

> resources?tid%255B%255D=25&tid_1%255B%255D=26&keys=

Ho can I stop Drupal changing the path so the links works as I want it to?

Comment: Everything after and including the `?` is not part of the path, so you can't use it as such. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33636/how-to-add-a-link-in-a-menu-with-query-parameters-in-paths for some alternatives

Comment: Thank you Clive, answer is here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33636/how-to-add-a-link-in-a-menu-with-query-parameters-in-paths